# How to remove the dot in to_char if the number is an integer

Tags: postgresql

I need to perform to_char on a numeric field in postgresql. I am not able to come up with the right format string yet. I would like to get some help.

```
test=# select to_char(1.2, 'FM9999.9999'), to_char(1, 'FM9999.9999'), to_char(1.2212, 'FM9999.9999');
 to_char | to_char | to_char
---------+---------+---------
 1.2     | 1.      | 1.2212
(1 row)
```

Basically, I should not have the dot if there is are no places after the decimal places. `to_char(1, fstring)` should result in `1`, but `to_char(1.23, fstring)` should result in '1.23'. I need the `to_char` to behave exactly like `str()` function in python. For instance in python console:

```
>>> str(1.2)
'1.2'
>>> str(1)
'1'
>>> str(1.23)
'1.23'
```

closest solution I can find is to use the cast function.

```
=# select cast(1 as text), cast(1.2 as text), cast(12.3 as text), cast(1.0 as text);
 text | text | text | text
------+------+------+------
 1    | 1.2  | 12.3 | 1.0
```

Is there a way to use format string achieve the same. If so, can someone help me with the right format string?

Comment: I can't think of a way to convince to_char() to do this, but you could use  `trim()` to do this: `trim(to_char(1, 'FM9999.9999'), '.')`

Comment: Why do you you want to use format mask? What's wrong with cast()?

Comment: This is an auto generated code format string based on how used wants his data to be displayed. If the user does not specify anything, I would like to specify default format to postgres instead of having to write code that used to_char in one case and cast in another case. Just for consistency I guess.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for the answer. Nice username BTW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function:

```
create function to_ch (value numeric, format text)
returns text language sql as $$
    select rtrim(to_char(value, format), '.')
$$;

select to_ch(1.2, 'FM9999.9999'), to_ch(1, 'FM9999.9999'), to_ch(1.2212, 'FM9999.9999');

 to_ch | to_ch | to_ch  
-------+-------+--------
 1.2   | 1     | 1.2212
(1 row)
```

Variant with predefined format (maybe more handy):

```
create function to_ch4 (value numeric)
returns text language sql as $$
    select rtrim(to_char(value, 'FM9999.9999'), '.')
$$;

select to_ch4(1.2), to_ch4(1), to_ch4(1.2212);

 to_ch4 | to_ch4 | to_ch4 
--------+--------+--------
 1.2    | 1      | 1.2212
(1 row)
```