# strip zeros from fractional part from a number (NumericType) in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am searching for a function that enables me to strip the trailing 
zeros in the fractional part of a number (numeric type). For example, a 
number saved in a column of type numeric as such: 23.45000 would be 
returned as 23.45

I can't find any function that does this in the documentation, does 
something like this exist or do I need to write some custom function 
myself?

Comment: See [Two questions for formatting timestamp and number using postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35226792/1995738)

Answer (score 0):

It's not particularly elegant, but will do the trick:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(numeric_value::text, '^(-??\d*?\.\d*?)0*$', '\1');
```

Comment: thanks for the response. its working fine when we have number after decimal, but we have no like 1000.00 then the output is 10000. what would be the regular expression to remove the dot if its doesn't have any value after decimal.

Comment: I wouldn't change the regular expression in that case, but wrap the whole thing in `rtrim(..., '.')`.

Answer (score 0):

I modify Laurenz answer:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(rate_percent::text, '^(-?\d*?\.)(\d+?)0*$', '\1\2');
```

So, If you need to get 2.0 (float), you should use my variant. In Laurenz regexp 2.0 converted to 2.